# Inequality on sequence of integers whose only prime factors are $2$ or $3$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Let $M=\lbrace 2^i 3^j | i,j \geq 0\rbrace$ and denote by 
$m_k$ the $k$-th element of $M$ ; so $m_1=1,m_2=2,m_3=3,m_4=4,m_5=6\ldots$.
Is it true that $3m_k\geq 2m_{k+1}$ for every $k>1$ ?

My thoughts : If $m_k$ is not a power of $3$, then $\frac{m_k}{2}$ is an integer
and is in $M$ ; the same can be said about $\frac{3m_k}{2}$. By
the definition of $m_{k+1}$ we then have $m_{k+1} \geq \frac{3m_k}{2}$ as wished.
So we can assume that $m_k$ is a power of $3$. Similarly we can assume 
that $m_{k+1}$ is a power of $2$. Then I am stuck.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be too difficult to prove a related result that for any multiplier $A>1$ the inequality $m_{k+1}\le A m_k$ holds for all sufficiently large $k$. Unless I'm mistaken this follows because (by Dirichlet/Kronecker density theorem) there exist fractions
$3^p/2^q, 2^r/3^s\in(1,A)$ with suitable natural numbers $p,q,r,s$. And if you are far enough in your sequence then $m_k=2^i3^j$ such that either $i\ge q$ or $s\ge j$. Of course, the point of your question is to make this hold for **all** $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $m_{k+1} = 2^p$ with $p \ge 2$, $\dfrac{3}{4} m_{k+1} \in M$.

Comment: ... and $\frac{3}{4}\geq \frac{2}{3}$. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following cases:

- $\small2|m_k \implies \frac32m_k\in{M} \implies m_k<m_{k+1}\leq\frac32m_k \implies \color\red{3m_k\geq2m_{k+1}}$
- $\small3|m_k \implies \frac43m_k\in{M} \implies m_k<m_{k+1}\leq\frac43m_k \implies 4m_k\geq3m_{k+1} \implies \color\red{3m_k\geq}\frac94m_{k+1}>\color\red{2m_{k+1}}$

Comment: The first case is already in the OP, and the second is already in Robert Israel's answer.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: I read the question at the opening statement ("Is it true that..."), and addressed it. I did not make any comparisons with the other answer here, possibly because it appeared while I was trying to formulate my own idea. It makes sense that a question will have similar (or even identical) answers.

Comment: It also makes sense to delete a redundant answer. That's what I do when I realize that one of my answers brings nothing new to earlier answers. No need to clutter web space, right ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: I must say that your comments here feel rather ungrateful, even a bit rude, considering the help attempt you've been given. Not sure if that's a matter of ego or whatever, but I think that you should consider being a bit more thankful under similar circumstances. It's one thing if the answer was technically wrong, but it's not. And it's not even a duplicate of the other answer either. The general idea is indeed the same, but that is mostly the case in math (single question, single answer). The formulation of the idea is unique enough IMO.

Comment: The fact that you answered ignoring most of the OP (and ignoring a much earlier answer also) makes me doubt very much that bringing help was your principal intention. Given your reaction, I'd appreciate you not to interact with me anymore here on MSE. Thanks in advance